How can I add proxy only for Google BigQuery in Apache Superset?
I cannot use Google BigQuery directly from Apache Superset without a proxy. I added this code in superset/db_engine_specs/bigquery.py:
os.environ['https_proxy'] = 'http://USER:PASSWORD@IP:PORT'
and after that my BigQuery connections were successful again. But this line of code affected another connectors but I need proxy only for BigQuery.
Question: Is there any way to add proxy only for BigQuery and not affect other connectors. Because now os.environ affects all scripts inside Apache Superset (using docker compose)
I did not try much because I do not know how to solve this problem
